# Access denied when trying to download RDP file for Azure VM using Connect button

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azureportal

Click the Connect button to download the RDP file for a VM in Azure Portal results in...

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access is denied.
>
> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required
>   to serve this request. This may have been caused by an incorrect user
>   name and/or password.
>
> Error message 401.1: Logon credentials were not recognized. Make sure
>   you are providing the correct user name and password. Otherwise,
>   contact the Web server's administrator for help.

Tracing this I think I understand why as I see no creds are passed in any header.

The Request is a POST to

```
https://portal.azure.com/api/FileDownload?filename=<myVMfilename>.rdp&mimeType=application%2Frdp&dataType=text
```

This is on a Mac using Safari.

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Safari can't download Azure VM RDP file, please try to use other browser to download the RDP file, ex. Chrome.

Comment: To add to this, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge/Internet Explorer are the browsers that work best with the Azure portal.

Comment: yes that did work, was hoping there might be a setting I might be able to change.    PS.. the error message is coming back with the default error message. Might looked better if it was a handled error instead of IIS's default 401..   Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my hours.

Comment: This is a terrible user experience.